# convert NSDictionary's key into an NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

How can i convert the key to an NSNumber? this code gives me the error:

no matter how i try it, i always end up with the error: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'NSNumber' from 'NSIntegar' (aka 'int').

```
        for (id key in consultants)
    {
        consultantData = [[ConsultantData alloc] init];

        consultantData.name = [consultants objectForKey:key];
        consultantData.conID = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:key] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"name: %@    ID: %@", consultantData.name, consultantData.conID);

        [consultantList addObject:consultantData];
        [consultantData release];
    }
```

here is my object ConsultantData:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ConsultantData : NSObject 
{
    NSString *name;
    NSNumber *conID;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *conID;

@end

#import "ConsultantData.h"


@implementation ConsultantData

@synthesize name;
@synthesize conID;

-(void) dealloc
{
    [name release];
    [conID release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

if i try isMemberOfClass, it never returns true. if i try isKindOfClass, it tells me its a NSString.

consultants is a dictionary i receive from my sever that passes thru an XMLRPC function (server is PHP). from what i've seen, everything is a string in the server dictionary returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be that you have the order wrong.

```
consultantData.conID = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:key] integerValue];
```

means

```
NSNumber *foo = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:key];
NSInteger bar = [foo integerValue];
consultantData.conID = bar;
```

you probably want

```
consultantData.conID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[key integerValue]];
```

which is in verbose form:

```
NSInteger foo = [key integerValue];
NSNumber *bar = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:foo];
consultantData.conID = bar;
```

Comment: ha! that worked perfectly, thank you and thanks to the other guys who also provided the right answer. i banged my head against the wall far longer then i should have over this.

Answer (score 1):

> consultantData.conID = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:key] integerValue];

The above line should be:

```
consultantData.conID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[key integerValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key is an NSString, you can't pass the key to [NSNumber numberWithInteger:key] because it is not an integer!  Use the intValue method on the key to get an integer, then convert the integer to a NSNumber like so:

```
consultantData.conID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[key intValue]];
```

Comment: Your first point is incorrect. When used with fast enumeration, [dictionaries enumerate their keys](http://tinyurl.com/3sz3bpy). The `.allKeys` is not necessary.

Comment: Your are correct.  Apparently the times I left it out was when I wanted to iterate over the values.  Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

integerValue returns an NSInteger, which is not an NSNumber. You should pass the NSNumber directly:

```
consultantData.conID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[key integerValue]];
```